# Install SSL certificate only in CPanel

Tags: ssl, cpanel

Let me see if I can explain this clearly. I'm new to SSL certs.

I already got a SSL cert for my company domain xxxxxx.com and is installed in the Cpanel.
Now I have an A record created which is abc.xxxxxx.com and this will point to my local server ip (i created the A record for a web service usage)

Now my question is, since the A record abc.xxxxxx.com is already SSL encrypted, do I still need to install the ssl certificate in my local server? I have tried accessing the web service URL https://abc.xxxxxx.com on my browser and it looks fine with no security warnings. Am I good to go already?

Answer (score 0):

> I have tried accessing the web service URL https://abc.xxxxxx.com on my browser and it looks fine with no security warnings.

The subject (or better: subject alternative names) of the subject must match the hostname given in the URL. Since you don't get any browser warnings it is likely that your certificate already covers `abc.xxxxxx.com`, for example because the certificate is valid for `*.xxxxxx.com` (wildcard certificate).

Comment: Yes, it is a wildcard certificate. So I guess I don't need to install it on my local server already?

Comment: @user3543512: since you already have the certificate installed and it works you don't need to install it again.

Answer (score 0):

> Now my question is, since the A record abc.xxxxxx.com is already SSL encrypted, do I still need to install the ssl certificate in my local server?

Yes. The certificate is not being installed into DNS, and there is **no such thing** as "SSL encrypted A record". It's the direct communications between client and *web server* that are SSL encrypted, so each server has to present its own certificate independently (to prove that it is authorized to host that domain).

(Indeed that's a large part of why SSL/TLS is being used – it's to protect against spoofed DNS responses pointing at the wrong server.)

Comment: So you are saying that, although I can access https:// abc.xxxxxx.com without any warnings, I am still not SSL-protected?

Comment: No. I am saying that although you can access it without any warnings *now*, this does not mean you will be able to access it without warnings once you point it to a different HTTPS server.

Comment: Actually it is already pointing to my local server via a public IP. My local server does not have SSL cert installed yet. CPanel is at my hosting company. In the A record I set it to point to the public IP which will then be port forwarded to my local server. Then why is it not showing a warning now?